# starting hadoop via php using the command shell_exec()

Tags: php, shell, hadoop

actually i want to start my Hadoop cluster via PHP. i have use the PHP command shell_exec(), but its not working. how can i resolve this?
Below is the code I've tried:

```html
<?php
$output = shell_exec("/usr/local/hadoop3/sbin/start-dfs.sh");
echo "<pre>" . $output . "</pre>";

?>
```

hadoop starts well when i type the command sbin/start-dfs.sh" on the terminal

Comment: I would strongly suggest not running Hadoop on the same machine as a PHP web server for security reasons

Comment: actually i need this to start via my web page button. how to do this?

Comment: I understand that, but you currently are required to have Hadoop and PHP running on the same machine. As I mentioned before, Ambari does exactly what you are trying to build here (it uses Python+SSH to start/stop Hadoop)